# How can I skip an entire comment line by using fgets even after the set maximum nr of chars

Tags: c

I'm reading lines from a file and I might have a comment anywhere throughout it of any size.

```
        while (fgets(line, 100, myFile))
        {
            // skip and print comment
            if (line[0] == '#') printf("Comment is = %s", line);
            else {...}

         }
```

The code is doing what is supposed to until it gets a comment which is over 100 characters. In that case it will not detect the `#` anymore and it won't skip it. How can I solve this?

Comment: If you're reading lines longer than 100 chars and you want to process them all at once, you need a line buffer bigger than 100.  Simple as that. (And if the line might truly be of any size, then a  fixed-size array that you read into with `fgets` is not the right choice.  You might look at `getline`.)

Comment: Thank you. I'll have a read about `getline`.

Answer (score 0):

You could introduce a state variable to tell the program that you are on comment
mode. Like this:

```
// mode == 0 --> normal
// mode == 1 --> comment, remove/ignore comments
int mode = 0;
char line[100];
while(fgets(line, sizeof line, myFile))
{
    char *newline = strchr(line, '\n');

    if(mode == 1)
    {
        if(newline)
            mode = 0; // restore normal mode

        continue; // ignore read characters
    }

    char *comment = strchr(line, '#');

    if(comment)
    {
        *comment = '\0';

        if(newline == NULL)
            mode = 1; // set comment mode
    }

    // process your line without the comment
}
```

If a comment is found, `strchr` returns a pointer to that location. Setting it
to `'\0'` allows you to process the line without a comment. If the comment is
larger than `line` can hold, then the newline character is not found. In that case
you have to skip the next read bytes of `fgets`, until you find a newline.
That's when the `mode` variable comes in handy, you set it to 1 so the next
iterations can ignore the line if a newline is not found.

Answer (score 0):

`fgets` itself will tell you when it did not read the entire line:

> The `fgets()` function reads bytes from the stream into the array pointed to by s, until n−1 bytes are read, **or a newline character is read and transferred to s**, or an end-of-file condition is encountered. The string is then terminated with a null byte.
>   (https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E36784_01/html/E36874/fgets-3c.html)

So if your just-read line starts with `#` but does not end with `\n` (and `fgets` does not indicate EOF), read and skip all next 'lines' until you either find the end of the current 'line' indicated by a terminating `\n`, or you encounter an EOF condition.

If you want to store the comment for later display (as you are doing), use `malloc` and `realloc` to create and enlarge memory for the comment itself. Do not forget to free it after you're done.